# Who initially raised Naruto?

Tags: naruto

We know that Naruto's parents died right after his birth, and by the time he was in the Academy he was living alone. However, there must have been a period of time when he was being raised by someone, because babies can't take care of themselves. Is it ever said who raised him for that initial time or where he lived?